# Get users by taxonomy id in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I have created groups in wordpress using 'WP User Groups' and am trying to get users that I have put into the groups. I can get the taxonomy term ids to show and i can see that in the term_relationships table in the database the users are linked to the taxonomy ids there by 'object id'.

```
<?php

$myarray = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'user-group',
    'hide_empty' => false
) );

foreach($myarray as $myarr){
    echo $myarr->term_taxonomy_id."<br>";
}

?>
```

Can anyone help me to return the users associated with the taxonomy term (group). Thank you.